# NameError: Uninitialized constant Linked_Test::Nill

Tags: ruby, linked-list, nameerror

I'm trying to create a test through minitest to test my class LinkedList.

I'm receiving this error message:

```
1) Error:
Linked_ListTest#test_next_node_after_head_is_nil:
NameError: uninitialized constant Linked_ListTest::Nil
test/linked_list_test.rb:26:in `test_next_node_after_head_is_nil'

This is my test:
24 def test_next_node_after_head_is_nil
25  list = LinkedList.new
26  assert_equal Nil, head.next_node
27 end
```

My expected behavior is:

> list.head.next_node
>       => nil

This is my LinkedList class

```
class LinkedList

 attr_reader :head


 def initialized(data = nil)
  @head = Node.new(data)
 end

 def append(sound)
 "doop"
 end

 def next_node
  nil
 end


end
```

I'm unsure what that error means for line 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that case matters, `nil` exists in ruby (stands for *NULL*), but `Nil` do not; so use `nil` instead of `Nil` in your assertion:

```
assert_equal nil, head.next_node
```

Comment: must have been the no breaks that made me overlook that. thanks!

Comment: @Sam Glad to help! Please don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking the tick). :)

Comment: no problem! (I did just don't have enough reps for it show I believe)

Comment: @Sam Rep is only needed if you want to upvote (clicking up arrow) or downvote (clicking down arrow) he answer; but you can _mark an answer as accepted_ (clicking the tick) with any rep (there is no restriction).